# Jquery val() does not recheck / reevaluate the value

Tags: php, jquery

short description 
I'm using jquery, jqueryUI and ajax.

I use val() to get value from a field the first time it does it perfectly 
but if I change the value in the field the value stay the same.

Long descriptionn 
I'm developing a big project I have ~2 years on this project 
My head is pumping! ;)

I have something like this :

this is the html for the div :

```
<div id="add_task_diag" style="display: none">
   <label for="task">Task : </label><input id="taskfrm" label="Task" value="task" name="taskval" placeholder="e.g fill in tax form" />
   <button value="submit" class="btn btn-large add_task_frm">Add task</button> <button class="btn btn-large cancel_add_task">Cancel</button>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="add_task"><i class="icon-file icon-white"></i> Add Todo</button>
```

this is the script :

```
<script>
$(".add_task_frm").click(function() {
    function taskgen() {
        var data = "task=" + $("#taskfrm").val();
        alert(data); // only for debuging
        var task_data = data;
        alert(task_data); // only for debuging
        $.post("whereitneedtogo.php?task=action80", task_data), //this is the ajax part
        $("#add_task_diag").dialog("destroy"); // I had here close I changed it to "destroy"
        task_data = undefined; //I tried to unset the variable
    }
    taskgen();
});​
</script>
```

When I run it everything work fine! when I resend with another value the variable stays the same. e.g if I put test123 in the field in the seccond test it will stay test123 
I need to reload the page to reset the variable.

I don't want to use location.reload()

this file is 1700+ lines long but this is the part where the problem is.

I tried alot of things like :
- setting my script after Dom is ready 
- setting my variables to undefined or null 
- destroy the jquery tabs 
- the only part seems to be working for me is location.reload but my application is full ajax.

Thank for helping I hope this is stupid or easy one .

Comment: Have you tried to move the function declaration outside the click event handler?

Comment: @Philipp this is most certainly the answer

Comment: It works correctly for me..each time I click the todo button, whatever value is in the textbox gets alerted correctly..

Comment: Philip no I did not try until now ..... you see very stupid one , but alot of coding make me things blind ... THANK YOU MY FRIEND !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to declare and call the function every time you click.. Try moving it outside the click event handler..

```
<script>
$(".add_task_frm").click(function() {
    taskgen();
});​

function taskgen() {
        var data = "task=" + $("#taskfrm").val();
        alert(data); // only for debuging
        var task_data = data;
        alert(task_data); // only for debuging
        $.post("whereitneedtogo.php?task=action80", task_data), //this is the ajax part
        $("#add_task_diag").dialog("destroy"); // I had here close I changed it to "destroy"
        task_data = undefined; //I tried to unset the variable
    }

</script>
```

You might also encounter scoping issues when you want to call the taskgen() from some other place..

Answer (score 0):

It's because you define your closure inside the click handler. Move the `taskgen` function outside of the click handler, wrap everything in `$(document).ready()` and you should be good to go! See below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".add_task_frm").click(function() {
       taskgen();
    });

    function taskgen() {
       var data = "task=" + $("#taskfrm").val();

       alert(data); // only for debuging
       var task_data = data;
       alert(task_data); // only for debuging
       $.post("whereitneedtogo.php?task=action80", task_data), //this is the ajax part
       $("#add_task_diag").dialog("close").dialog("destroy"); // I usually chain 'close' and 'destroy'
    }

});
```

Comment: Daniel thanks! and thank you for the tip of chaining destroy and close !